# TFS Code Churn Counts Indentation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, indentation, churn

Being involved in a software measurement project. We want to use TFS Code churns to determine the size of each project we have. Following this [instruction](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html), we have reached the code churns in a specific duration of time. Unfortunately TFS counts indentations into code churns! 
Is there any way to tell TFS not to count indentations and white-spaces in code churns?

Environment:
TFS 2012, Visual Studio 2010, 2012

Comment: I think he just means following the link to the report.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link!

Answer (score 0):

The Code Churn report isn't measuring size of the project. It's measuring the amount of change in the project. Change of whitespace is also change of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want the meaningful changes like what you see in file comparison tools like Araxis (they can ignore indentations, ...)

Comment: Ok, forget about project size. Why something that does not changes the logic (if it can be identified) should be counted as change? I think there is a direct relation between meaningful change and test effort.